# Iterating through lists within a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My original pandas DataFrame looks like this:

```
df =

    Person_ID | trip_purpose | trip_start_time | trip_end_time
    -----------------------------------------------------------
         1    |    'Work'    |   05:40:00      |  05:42:00
         2    |   'School'   |   06:40:00      |  06:45:00
         1    |   'Leisure'  |   05:52:00      |  06:37:00
         1    |    'Home'    |   06:40:00      |  06:49:00  
        ...
```

First step: group by Person_ID:

```
df = df.groupby('Person_ID').agg(lambda x : ','.join(x).split(',')) 
# this is faster than grouping by .agg(list)
```

Result of grouping:

```
Person_ID |   trip_purpose   | trip_start_time | trip_end_time
---------------------------------------------------------------
          |    ['Work',      |   [05:40:00,    |  [05:42:00,
     1    |     'Leisure',   |    05:52:00,    |   06:37:00,
          |     'Home']      |    06:40:00]    |   06:49:00]
          |                  |                 |
     2    |   ['School']     |   [06:40:00 ]   |  [06:45:00]   
    ...
```

In the next step, I want to calculate the time the person spent on each activity between the trips and write it into a specific column. 
Since my agents start their day at home the fist activity is always "living", meaning, that that `duration_activity_1` is given by the first start time

`pd.to_timedelta(df['trip_start_time'].apply(lambda x: x[0]))`.

This means if Person 1 makes 3 trips he/she has 4 activities because he/she starts at home.

The last activity lasts until midnight, meaning it is calculated by

`pd.to_datetime("23:59:59") - pd.to_datetime(df['trip_end_time').apply(lambda x: x[-1]))`

All the activities durations between the first and the last are calculated by substracting the start time of the current trip minus the end time of the last trip:

`pd.to_timedelta(df['trip_start_time'].apply(lambda x: x[i])) - pd.to_timedelta(df['trip_end_time'].apply(lambda x: x[i - 1]))]`

This is what it should look like:

```
Person_ID |   trip_purpose   | trip_start_time | trip_end_time | duration_activity_1 | duration_activity_2 | duration_activity_3 | duration_activity_4 | ...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          |    ['Work',      |   [05:40:00,    |  [05:42:00,   |                     |                     |                     |                     |  
     1    |     'Leisure',   |    05:52:00,    |   06:37:00,   |    05:40:00         |     00:10:00        |     00:03:00        |     17:14:00        |
          |     'Home']      |    06:40:00]    |   06:49:00]   |                     |                     |                     |                     |
          |                  |                 |               |                     |                     |                     |                     |
     2    |   ['School']     |   [06:40:00 ]   |  [06:45:00]   |    06:40:00         |     17:15:00        |          nan        |          nan        |
    ...
```

Since I want to compute in a scalar way and I have more than one condition I thought of `numpy.select()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

    for i in range(maximum_number_of_activities):
        condlist = [i == 0,    # first activity
                    i == df["trip_purpose"].apply(len),    # last activity
                    (i > 0) & (i < df["trip_purpose"].apply(len))]    # other activities
        choicelist = [pd.to_timedelta(df["trip_start_time"].apply(lambda x: x[0])),    # first activity starts at midnight and ends with the first trip
                      pd.to_datetime("23:59:59") - pd.to_datetime(df["trip_end_time"].apply(lambda x: x[-1])),    # last activity starts with the last trip and ends at midnight
                      pd.to_timedelta(df["trip_start_time"].apply(lambda x: x[i])) - pd.to_timedelta(df["trip_end_time"].apply(lambda x: x[i - 1]))]    # all other activities are calculated by substracting the start time of the current trip minus the end time of the last trip
        default = np.nan
        print(pd.DataFrame(np.select(condlist=condlist,
                                     choicelist=choicelist,
                                     default=default),
                           columns=[i]))

# I'm aware that this code is not assigning it to the original DataFrame.
```

And here is my problem: I get an `IndexError: list index out of range`

I suppose it has something to do with the 3rd condition in `choicelist`. I suppose that even if I catch the cases of `i == 0` and `i == df["trip_purpose"].apply(len)` I can't use the index variable `i` there, because the 3rd condition will not be valid?!? 
(I get the same result if I write `choicelist` directly into the `np.select` function.)

Can you think of a solution to this or to an alternative way to get my desired DataFrame? I would really appreciate your help.